# iOS how can i play a custom notifications sound file where it`s in Shared/AppGroup/xxx/Library/Sounds

Tags: ios, swift, audio, notifications

i have a audio file to custom notifications sound，but
when the file is in the /Library/Sounds directory of the app's container directory,it works.
when the file is in the /Library/Sounds directory of one of the app's shared group container directories.,it doesn't work
why?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound

Answer (score 0):

It works only in iOS 13 +
iOS12.1~13 use by local notification
iOS 10~12.1 custom use AVFoundation